# TargetParameterCountException when mocking function to return its input

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq

I have a function that requires mocking out to return one of its parameters.

The function looks as follows:

```
IEnumerable<XDocument> WrapDocuments(MessageSettings messageSettings, IEnumerable<XDocument> documents);
```

I am mocking it like this:

```
mockDocumentWrapper
    .Setup(m => m.WrapDocuments(It.IsAny<MessageSettings>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<XDocument>>()))
    .Returns((IEnumerable<XDocument> x) => x);
```

When the test which invokes `WrapDocuments()` runs, I get a `TargetParameterCountException`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate used in the `Returns` does not match the amount of parameters passed in the setup. The method expects 2 arguments so the delegate should also expect the same.

```
mockDocumentWrapper
    .Setup(_ => _.WrapDocuments(It.IsAny<MessageSettings>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<XDocument>>()))
    .Returns((MessageSettings m, IEnumerable<XDocument> docs) => docs);
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution and I feel daft for not knowing it!